# Application using Google APIs:10

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

I've opened an old project which is using Google API 10.

after updating with SDK Manager to the newest update (API 14, ect.) 
google removed API 10 and it no longer comes with the sdk.

so now when i open my Project with Eclipse it says: 
"Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:10'"

Is there a way to:
  1) Download the old Google API 10  ?
  2) To make this project use the updated APIs and not to obligate 
     me to the old Google API 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer! and it wasn't trivial to my opinion....

I went to "project.properties" file, and i had a row there says:

"target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:10"

and I changed it to:

"target=android-10"...

Thanks everybody for trying to help.

Comment: This file says: # This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!

Answer (score 2):

SDK Manager in Eclipse should allow you to download SDKs back to API version 3.

And for the second question: updating those attributes in your AndroidManifest file should serve the purpose:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="X"
    android:targetSdkVersion="X" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your SDK Manager, you can download all SDK versions back to API 3.
You can have them all and just work with them separately, you're not bound to using one single API version.

Comment: it's not true. open your SDK folder, <sdk>\platforms, and you wouldn't find android-5 folder for example. they delete for you. for sure.
same for some of google APIs

Comment: Only the versions that aren't being used anymore as far as I know. 
I checked my folder and I have all versions from android-3 to android-14. Only missing 5 and 6 but I'm pretty sure those aren't used at all anymore. Seems like they went from 4 to 7 in one go.