# Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: android

link for files please solve if possible then forward me Link : drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjnJ7qmzQucdnNwZUdscjA1OTg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application using Google APIs:10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375560/application-using-google-apis10)

Comment: you need to change your API target with the API level available in your sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update some SDK Tools like it says, open the SDK Manager and update.

> The Android SDK Manager provides the SDK tools, platforms, and other
>   components you need to develop your apps.
>
> To open the SDK Manager, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click
>   SDK Manager  in the toolbar.
>
> When an update is available for a package you already have, a dash 
>   appears in the check box next to the package.
>
> To update an item or install a new one, click the check box so it
>   shows a checkmark. To uninstall a package, click to clear the check
>   box. Pending updates are indicated in the left column with a download
>   icon . Pending removals are indicated with a red cross .
>
> To update the selected packages, click Apply or OK, then agree to any
>   license agreements.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html for more information

Comment: 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:10' i can't find this to update/install ?

Comment: It should be under SDK platforms, you need API 10 which is 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) see https://postimg.org/image/aigibd8gv/

Comment: i installed but this error came out Error:(16, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_14bv95svuxga1leddp74hsyn7$_run_closure2@60ba684c] on root project 'BookStore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Sushant\Desktop\BookStore\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: link for files please solve if possible then forward me Link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjnJ7qmzQucdnNwZUdscjA1OTg